# Add validation dynamically from database

Tags: html, laravel, database, validation, dynamic-values

I want to set some validation from database in input tag.

Here i am trying to set validation in form , from database ,

This is how i have stored my validation values in database comma separated

[image]

I have tried to put validation like this but it is not working , how to keep these both validation here in input tag in laravel

This is my input tag

```
<input  type="{{$data->inputType}}" class="form-control" required id="customField[0][name]" value="{{$data->customInputName}}"
                      name="customField[0][name]"  placeholder="Pool Party" aria-label="Pool Party" {{$data->validation}}/>
```

Comment: You need to add what you have tried to the code so we can help you understand what is not working with it.

Comment: What's the plan behind putting f.e. `required,alpha` as input _attributes_? That won't validate anything

Comment: i am inserting those values using check-boxes in comma separated string @brombeer

Comment: keep in mind that while frontend validation can be good UX, it is just that, you need to run these validations again in your backend